# Invoke user control/main page method when UWP app gets suspended

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have a custom user control (UWP) I need to invoke one of its methods when the UWP App enters on suspension mode **OnSuspending method (App.cs)**, another approach is call a method located in MainPage

It is possible to achieve this ?

Comment: are you looking for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556492/best-way-to-access-current-instance-of-mainpage-in-a-windows-store-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your control can implement it's own OnSuspending handler, like this:

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MyUserControl_Loaded;
    this.Unloaded += MyUserControl_Unloaded;                
}

private void MyUserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Suspending += MyUserControl_Suspending;
}

private void MyUserControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Suspending -= MyUserControl_Suspending;
}

private void MyUserControl_Suspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    // your control's OnSuspending code here
}
```